# How to make DIV width be flexible UP TO the width of the viewport

Tags: html, css, user-interface, user-experience

I've got a table that is contained by a div.

My two requirements:

1. The container div should be only as wide as the table it contains.
2. At maximum, the container div should be only as wide as the viewport (using `using overflow-x: scroll` to see the whole table.

I can achieve the first requirement with `display: table`, `display: inline-block`, or `display: inline-table`.

I can achieve the second requirement with `display: block`.

I can't see to nail both requirements. I have tried every display option available in CSS3, but none produce the results I'm seeing. Is it even possible without using javascript?

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5VBPm/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

putting `display: inline-block` will suffice for the container div and leaving the `overflow-x: scroll`.  I forked your fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/khcQZ/

Are you using any other containing divs beyond the div that you have?

Comment: Yes I am, but only the typical #wrapper and #contents divs. I think it was the max-width: 100% that I added at the last minute that made it work.

Comment: Yes, the inline-block width depends on the parent width, so if any of the parent divs dont have any widths setup, then they will default to the body and html definitions.  Depending on the case it is somewhat useful to apply a width (and or height) of 100% to the html,body definitions so that they will stretch all the way through to the viewport.  HTH!